# How to get transaction history on a particular key in Hyperledger Fabric?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

I have a Hyperledger Fabric network with multiple peers with corresponding StateDB (CouchDB) and I have given CORE_LEDGER_HISTORY_ENABLEHISTORYDATABASE=true in all peer configuration under docker compose file. The idea that I shall be able to retrieve the update history of a record basis the key. The key here is a trade number and whenever any attribute of Trade gets updated, I do see update happening in CouchDB as I see increase in revision value. Now, in my chaincode function, have added below snippet of code (sample code for now)

_, args := stub.GetFunctionAndParameters()

```
tradeNumber := args[1]

historyIer, err := stub.GetHistoryForKey(tradeNumber)

if err != nil {
    fmt.Println(err.Error())
    return shim.Error(err.Error())
}

if historyIer.HasNext() {
    modification, err := historyIer.Next()
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err.Error())
        return shim.Error(err.Error())
}
fmt.Println("Returning information about", string(modification.Value))
```

}
    return shim.Success(nil)

However, everytime I check chaincode container, it prints only the last value of Trade than the number of updates it has gone through, can anybody please let me know what wrong am I doing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, the problem that using the history iterator only once instead of actually iterating over it.

Instead of:

```
if historyIer.HasNext() {
    modification, err := historyIer.Next()
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err.Error())
        return shim.Error(err.Error())
    }
    fmt.Println("Returning information about", string(modification.Value))
}
```

You need to do:

```
for historyIer.HasNext() {
    modification, err := historyIer.Next()
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err.Error())
        return shim.Error(err.Error())
    }
    fmt.Println("Returning information about", string(modification.Value))
}
```

which is going to iterate over all key updates and print values.

Comment: Thanks Artem, it did solve the issue... Just one point for my clarity, when I looked in the CouchDB it does have the updated version of data then where does SHIM API gets the history data from...

Comment: @AshwaniKumar the HistoryDB implementation in fabric  stores a "pointer" to the block/transaction where its value was modified. This "pointer" is stored in a levelDB store on the peer. When you query the history later on, fabric will grab this pointer and fetch from the ledger the modification made to the key.